# C# Nancy.Hosting.Self doesn't answer to requests from network, only to localhost request

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2017, nancy, windows-console

I am trying to integrate nancy self hosting into my wpf project and when I start my program, I am able to connect to rest api from local browser, but cannot connect from another computer.

```
HostConfiguration hostConfigs = new HostConfiguration();
hostConfigs.UrlReservations.CreateAutomatically = true;

NancyHost host = new NancyHost(hostConfigs, new Uri("http://localhost:1234"));
host.Start();
```

Is there a way I can set Uri to wildcard, like in other built in web servers, 0.0.0.0 or + ?

EDIT
**Windows firewall is disabled!!**
I've also tried with different configurations of host, with http://10.10.10.149:1234" as a host. I've tryed "http://+:1234, this one doesn't build, it throws error.

I've also completely removed hostConfigs and added ACL to the system by running some commands in powershell, like suggested in many articles:

```
netsh http add urlacl url="http://+:12345/" user="Everyone"
```

Still, can only connect from local browser, not from another network location. Whenever I try to connect to machine where program is running via rest api, I get 503 Service Unavailable.

Comment: Are you sure this doesn't work from another computer? Have you eliminated firewalls as the issue blocking it from being accessed?

Comment: How are you connecting to it? What address are you using?

Comment: Again, you didn't tell me what address you're using to connect to the application.

Comment: That’s still not a full address.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to change it to `"http://+:1234"` to bind to all network interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced with a similar problem. I searched a lot of discussions and I had no answer. Then I found previous messages. I worked for me.

It was a firewall issue.
And the solution;

1- Go to firewall settings
2- Inbound firewall rules
3- Add a new rule
4- Connection point (TCP / UDP)
5- TCP
6- (Enter port numbers)
7- Allow connection

I have shared my experience in case anyone need it.